# ModelBuilder to iterate through multiple rasters in different folders and setting to local memory

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I have many rasters contained in different folders with multiple types of data (tif, JSON, xml). The path to my data is as follows:  C:\Planet\2023\August

Within the august folder, there are 7 additional folders. I had to separate the files for download efficiency (order 1:7) For example: C:\Planet\2023\August"Order1...Order7" In each of the 7 order folders there are two types of images each representing a tile along a designated flight path:

3B_AnalyticMS_SR_8b.tif (this is the image)

3B_udm2.tif (this is the foot print)

Is there a way in ModelBuilder to pull all the AnalyticMS_SR_8b images either set to local memory and set the bands for each image OR combine all images to 1 and i can set the bands manually?

My current process is starting at the August folder, placing an iterator with wildcard = (Asterick)AnalyticMS(Asterick) and enabling recursive. From here, most tools i've applied isn't producing any results.

current process:
[image]

However, this "make raster layer" process ran for some time but didn't do anything that I could see.

Comment: Did you right click on the output of make raster layer and set it to _add to display_? It's also unclear what you are describing what you want to do when you say "...set the bands for each image...".